# Managing spacing correctly in `report` class

Tags: spacing, setspace

I am writing a long document using the `report` class. The format must be size A4, with a left-hand margin 4 cm., font size 12 and one-and-a-half spacing. So my .tex in minimal form would like this. Apart from the `\onehalfspacing` I have added `\setstretch{1.5}` because I realised that in many cases the space between math-display and text was not consistent within the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amscd,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsxtra,amstext,mathtools,
latexsym,bbm,enumitem,indentfirst,bm,emptypage,color,pifont,float}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

% set margins for double-sided printing
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setstretch{1.5} % fix the space between text and math-display
\setlist{nosep} % no separation between items in lists
```

This seems to solve the problem but now I have a similar 'inconsistent' spacing between text and titles, theorems or propositions (not always, only at some places in the document), like in these examples:

[image]
[image]

I have tried deleting

```
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setstretch{1.5} % fix the space between text and math-display
```

and the document looks excellent, but as I said, the one-and-a-half spacing is customary. Any ideas how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve it. Instead of using `\onehalfspacing` which seems to be a bit unstable, I am using

```
\linespread{1.3}
```

which also produces one half spacing.
Also, in this version the displays look very well spaced and there's no need of using `\setstretch{1.5}` any longer.